# Visual Studio Build Not Deploying Upon Build

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, build, azure-devops

I am trying to do a Visual Studio Build on TFS 2017.  So far, it seems to do the build, but will not do the standard Publish/Deploy I am used to on my local file system, with the Precompiled WCF app, etc.  This is what I have so far attached as images, and the PublishProfile I have switched to in desperation.  They have VS 2017 installed on the build server, and have updated the MS Build to the latest version.  Please help!  :)

[Visual Studio Build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZPNV.png)

[VM Deploy XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Tjco.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the build log to see whether the deployment executed.
2. Run the MSBuild command locally on the build agent machine to see whether it works.
3. Try the following arguments:

`/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:publishUrl="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\" /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish`

Comment: Would the console output show if the deployment executed?  In the console, I don't see the usual "Publish executed" I do on my local machine.

Comment: You could set variable `system.debug` to `true`, and check the log. You could also share the entire log (mask personal information) in your original post.